# How to remove Wordpress taxonomy description from paged pages

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm attempting to remove or prevent the  from being added to is_paged() taxonomy pages (tag and category pages).

I'm not sure if it is possible to remove, however is it possible to set a condition that this class is only added is the page is NOT is_paged(). This will prevent the class="clr tax-desc" from being displayed on page 2, page 3, page 4, etc of my category and tag pages.

I only want the class="clr tax-desc" to be present on the main page (or page 1) of the relevant category and tag pages.

I need to create something along the lines of:

```
if ( is_archive() && !is_paged()) {
Remove <div class="clr tax-desc"></div> 
}
```

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken, does the description under the category name have the class entry-meta?

If you give this class in your css the property

```
display:none;
```

then it will be hidden from your pages.

So add this line into your css and it should be gone.

```
.entry-meta { display:none; }
```

Comment: I'm currently using css to hide the section. However, as I display ads in that section I would like for that section to be removed completed from the HTML code of paged pages...